# recoding race into a single column from multiple columns

Tags: r

I am hoping to receive some insight on the best way to go about what I'm trying to do with my dataset. I am coding for race and each option was given there own column and coded with a '1' for yes and '0' for no. I would like to recode every one that was checked as a '1' into a single column with different numbers...(for instance, 1=white 2=black, etc). Would the best option be to recode with different numbers first, then combine into a single column?

```
# this is my data using the dput function
> dput(head(NewRace, 20))
structure(list(hhm1_race___1 = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", NA, 
"1", NA, "1", "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
NA), hhm1_race___2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, "0", NA, 
"0", "2", NA, NA, "2", NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", NA), hhm1_race___hispanic = c("0", 
"3", "3", "0", "0", NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", NA), hhm1_race___3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", NA), hhm1_race___4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, "0", 
NA, "0", "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA), 
    hhm1_race___5 = c("6", "6", "6", "6", "6", NA, "0", NA, "0", 
    "0", NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
#this is what i tried to use in terms of code
NewRace %>%
  mutate(new_race = as.integer(apply(across(starts_with("hhm1_race")), 1, which.max)),
         new_race_sum = apply(across(starts_with("hhm1_race")), 1, function(x) {sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)}),
         new_race = case_when(new_race_sum == 0 ~ NA_integer_,
                              new_race_sum == 1 ~ new_race,
                              new_race_sum  > 1 ~ 99L)) %>%
  select(-new_race_sum)
```

this is what the error message reads

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `new_race_sum`.
ℹ `new_race_sum = apply(...)`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I hope my thought process is not too confusing when put into words, any advice would be appreciated for the most logical way to go about this!

Comment: The question is more about if your example matches reality. I.e. in reality race is not a "single-select" entity, i.e. people can have several race (e.g. Black & Asian). That's probably the reason why your data is in this multi-select format. So what you also need to echk is if someone qualfies for several races. and code that into its own group of "two or more races".

Comment: Check this source for some input on the general topic: https://verstaresearch.com/newsletters/how-to-ask-race-ethnicity-on-a-survey/#main-article

So question is : in your data, is it possible that one person qualifies for multiple races?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple tidyverse solution. UPDATE: used the new data update provided by TO. Note also that I decided to code multi-race people as 99, but you might want to choose any other number that you like.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.integer),
         new_race = as.integer(apply(across(everything()), 1, which.max)),
         new_race_sum = apply(across(starts_with("hhm")), 1, function(x) {sum(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE)}),
         new_race = case_when(new_race_sum == 0 ~ NA_integer_,
                              new_race_sum == 1 ~ new_race,
                              new_race_sum  > 1 ~ 99L)) %>%
select(-new_race_sum)
```

Comment: Thank you deschen, the data does allow for a multi-race option in which they checked more than 1 and could elaborate (via a written-in response). I think you are absolutely correct in that it's necessary to reflect this with an option that qualifies for multiple races.

Comment: In that case the code above would not work and needs to be adjusted.

Comment: See updated code above. Note I decided to code all "multi race" people as 99. Note also taht I had to adjust your example a bit (see second-to-last row) to have one example for multi-race.

Comment: hey deschen, thank you again for all of your help -- I really appreciate you. I am getting this error, do you know what I might have done wrong?


`Error: Problem with mutate() column new_race_sum.
ℹ new_race_sum = apply(...).
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument `

Comment: Where do you get this error? When using your example data and my code pr when applying the code to your real data? If the latter, please provide an example of your real data, e.g. by using dput(head(your data, 20)) along with the code you were running.

Comment: I am using my own data, i used the code you send for the mock data and that worked perfectly, so i think i'm not editing it in the correct way to use for my data. I edited the original comment so you could hopefully see what I mean, let me know if not though. I'm just learning recently so I'm not sure if i entered it the best way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236865/discussion-between-lziegs-and-deschen).

Comment: Your problem is that your numbers are actually coded as characters (see the quotation marks around each number), so we first need to recode as integers. Note also that you have a column for Hispanic. Hispanic is an origin or ethnicity, NOT a race. So you should probably exclude it here. Someone can be of Hispanic origin and their race might be White or Black or whatever.

Comment: That's right! Thank you for the catch, I just relayed this information to the person who created this measure. I am going to try to code as integers. Again, thank you for being so kind, you've been so helpful as I'm trying to learn this!